# Cannot find element with Selenium Webdriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with Python and hit a problem where I cannot find an element. I'm trying to select the h2 element (or its containing div) in the table:

```
<table class="TabStrip" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="padding-top: 0px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
<td style="white-space: nowrap;vertical-align:bottom;">
    <div class="TabInactive"> </div>
    <div class="TabNotSelected" onmouseout="previousSibling.className='TabInactive'" onmouseover="previousSibling.className='TabActiveRIA'" tabindex="10" onblur="blurTab(event);" onfocus="focusTab(event);" onkeydown="postBackOnEnter(event, 'b$_tab-flexiKB01P112', null, '1', 'TAB|b$_tab-flexiKB01P112');" onclick="postBackOnEnter(event, 'b$_tab-flexiKB01P112', null, '0', 'TAB|b$_tab-flexiKB01P112');" data-name="b$_tab-flexiKB01P112" style="white-space: nowrap" role="tab" aria    -expanded="false">
        <h2 class="PageTabTitleNotSelected">Workflow Approval</h2>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="TabFiller" style="width:100%;"> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If I use:

```
row = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//table[@class="TabStrip"]/tbody/tr[1]')))
```

to select the row, everything works fine. But as soon as I try to add the cell:

```
cell = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//table[@class="TabStrip"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[15]')))
```

or anything within it, I get a timeout and element not found.

The content I'm after is plainly visible in the browser. Any ideas on where I might be going wrong?

**EDIT**

Everything works fine within the Selenium IDE using:

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//td[15]/div[2]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This also fails for any of the cells - not just the 15th.

Comment: Is the table loaded with AJAX interaction? Can you try to retrieve the h2 element without using any wait condition?

Comment: Yes, It's a commercial product (not mine!!) with AJAX everywhere.I have to use the wait in order to get anything on the page at all.

Comment: I've tried waiting for the row to be available, inserting an implicit wait and then looking for the cells in case they are being added later with some AJAX foo. No joy there either.

Comment: @Owen are you sure the first row has at least 15 `td` elements?

Comment: @alecxe Even if I just use td or td[1], I get the same failure

Comment: According to your edit and the javascript events associated with that row, can you please try to do a click event before selecting the element? This will trigger the javascript events and load the data.

Comment: @narko - struggling to do that. everything is within a similar table, so anything I try to click gives the same problem.

Comment: @narko I believe the IDE 'clickAndWait' command clicks the element specified and then waits before the next step, so there's no click before attempting to find the td[15]/div[2]

Comment: The point is what you can do with Selenium IDE you can do in code. Can you try to generate the code using the IDE and see what you get?

Comment: Exporting from the IDE to Python 2 gives me driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[15]/div[2]").click() and that fails with element not found

Comment: Another option, you can try to execute the javascript event directly with selenium. Please check this out: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script

Comment: have you tried css selector? i think u can easily found this by using css selector like :    div.TabNotSelected  >  h2.PageTabTitleNotSelected

Comment: @noor No, I haven't. But I shall this morning!

Comment: @narko I'll have a look at that idea too and let you know

Comment: css selector made no difference :-( Still cannot find element

Comment: using document.querySelector.... within execute_script is also failing to find the element

Comment: its really weird .. so much suggestion but till no end..ok ... have u tried by using invisibility Of Element and than try to get ur element? one more thing is there is something  mouse in, out action ...so is this element visible manually if mouse is not over the element or any other action?

Comment: It's all visible within the browser and I can't see any visibility settings at all. mouseover events just change the classes which changes the colour. All very odd

Comment: I've now tried using the Firefox scratchpad with javascript to find those elements and it can't see them either